# How to convert from rectangular to polar form using C# Complex

Tags: c#

Trying to convert a number from rectangular to polar form, ie from 20+j25 to 32<38.66

here's what i have so far:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Complex A = new Complex (0.4, 0.3);
        Complex B = new Complex (0.6, 0.7);
        Complex C = new Complex (24, 19);
        Complex D = A + B + C;

        Console.WriteLine (D);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

That gives me the answer 20, 25. which is in rectangular form. how would i go about making this polar?

Thanks

EDIT:
Ok i've made a few changes but still can't get the right answer. Using the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Complex RA = new Complex(25, 20);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} + i{1}", RA.Real, RA.Imaginary);

        double r, q;
        r = Math.Sqrt((RA.Real * RA.Real) + (RA.Imaginary * RA.Imaginary));
        q = Math.Atan(RA.Imaginary/RA.Real);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} < {1}", r, q);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I'm getting 32 < 0.647... the answer should be 32<38.66. Can anyone explain why i'm getting the wrong angle?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry i've got that backwards. Should say 25+j20, and the answer the program gives me is 25, 20

Comment: @MarkByers sorry, fixed that now

Comment: Just use Math.Sqrt(), Math.PI and friends.  I'm not sure if your question is about C#/.Net (just use namespace "Math" functions), or about polar/cartesian coordinates with complex numbers (Trig 101).

Comment: @paulsm4 can you show me how to use Math.PI? for example q = ((D.Imaginary / D.Real) * Math.PI / 180); doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Have to convert radians to degrees. Thanks for the help everyone!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Complex RA = new Complex(25, 20);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} + i{1}", RA.Real, RA.Imaginary);

        double r, q, z;
        r = Math.Sqrt((RA.Real * RA.Real) + (RA.Imaginary * RA.Imaginary));
        q = Math.Atan(RA.Imaginary/RA.Real);
        z = (q * (180/Math.PI));
        Console.WriteLine("{0} < {1}", r, z);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```